# Value_Counts() output in Python is a Series

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the # of sales by each type of video game. I have the categories shooter_games, platform_games, misc_games, and Roleplaying_games. I'm inputting this code to count the number of games in the category where they sold the most units in NA, JP, and EU:

```
Shooter_games.max_sales.value_counts()
```

and I get the following output:

```
NA_Sales 387
JP_Sales 99
EU_Sales 96
```

For some reason, when I put the exact code for Roleplaying_games, I get the following output:

```
Series([], Name: max_sales, dtype: int64)
```

Any idea why this is the case? This is the only category where the output is a series. Thanks!

Comment: what is the output of ```Roleplaying_games['max_sales'].unique()``` ?

Comment: the output is array([], dtype=object)

Comment: well, there is no values in the column. Please check by doing ```Roleplaying_games.head()```

Comment: Ah, I figured out what I did wrong. Need to pay attention to the upper/lower case lettering. Thanks!